# Where to put custom admin-related forms?

Tags: python, django

I successfully extended some admin model and form, but I'm not sure how to keep my file tree clean.

If I put `forms.py` at the same level as `admin.py`, everything work perfectly:

---

**forms.py**

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    #...

class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    #...
```

**admin.py**

```
from myapp.forms import MyUserCreationForm, MyUserChangeForm
```

**File tree**

```
mypackage/
    admin.py
    forms.py
```

---

Now, in order to have my admin-related forms separated from the other forms and make the code cleaner, I added a folder `admin` to put my admin-related forms. In that case URLs seem to be messed up. When going to /myapp/admin/ I get the default admin page, not the one I customized in my admin.py.

**admin/forms.py**

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    #...

class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    #...
```

**admin.py**

```
from myapp.admin.forms import MyUserCreationForm, MyUserChangeForm
```

**File tree**

```
mypackage/
    admin.py
    admin/
        forms.py
```

---

I guess the system is confused because admin is both a file and a folder. What's the standard way to keep custom admin-related files in Django?

**EDIT**: in the case shown above, there is a conflict between `admin.py` and the folder `admin`. I tried to put `admin.py` and `forms.py` in a folder, but it still does not work:

**admin/forms.py**

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    #...

class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    #...
```

**admin/admin.py**

```
from myapp.admin.forms import MyUserCreationForm, MyUserChangeForm

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    form = MyUserChangeForm
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm

    list_filter = ()

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'number', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff',)}),
    )


    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'number', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )


admin.site.register(MyUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

**File tree**

```
mypackage/        
    admin/
        forms.py
        admin.py
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: Are you receiving an error message? If so, what is it?

Comment: urls seem messed up. When going to `<myurl>/myapp/admin/` I get the default admin page, not the one I customized in my `admin.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to create an `__init__.py` file in your admin directory in order for it to be treated as a package.

```
mypackage/
    admin/
        __init__.py 
        forms.py
```

The `__init__.py` file is often empty. See the [Python docs on packages](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more information.

Secondly, you cannot have a directory called `admin` and a file `admin.py`. When you run `import myapp.admin`, python will ignore the `admin.py` file, and load  `admin/__init__.py` instead.

One possible solution is for you to move `admin.py` to `admin/__init__.py`. Then the following imports should work properly.

```
# in e.g. your urls.py
import myapp.admin # imports admin/__init__.py

# in e.g your admin/__init__.py:
from myapp.admin.forms import MyUserCreationForm, MyUserChangeForm # imports admin/forms.py
```

Comment: I already had the init.py file. I moved my admin.py to admin/, changed the import path, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: It's not clear what you've done when you say you've changed the import path, so I've updated my answer with the imports you should be using. Make sure you've restarted the Django server and removed any `pyc` files.

Comment: I put `admin.py` and `forms.py` in `myapp/admin/`. In `admin.py` I import my forms with `from myapp.admin.forms import MyUserCreationForm, MyUserChangeForm`, and my `urls.py` is the default one (I edited my question to add it). Doing that, I still cannot see my models' admins in `myurl/admin/`

Comment: Try adding print statements to your `__init__` and `forms.py` module to make sure they are being imported. You haven't shown the code you're using to register a custom model admin, so I can't tell whether that's correct or not.

Comment: I edited my question to show how I put everything in an `admin` folder.

Comment: You have moved `admin.py` to `admin/admin.py`. To import that, you would do `import myapp.admin.admin`. Try moving `admin.py` to `admin/__init__.py` as I suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> from myapp.forms import MyUserCreationForm, MyUserChangeForm

This will use the files current directory and search from that.

Try change that line to:

**from admin.forms import MyUserCreationForm, MyUserChangeForm**

Answer (score 0):

You can make a form folder and put all the forms there.